# styling nline cells

Tags: makecell

The number line command `\nline` from the makecell package inserts `n` cells with a pattern containing an incrementing number. I'd like to treat those as headers, styled with `\theadfont` and `\theadalign`. I looked at makecell's source, but I don't understand how patch it.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\footnotesize}
\renewcommand\theadalign{cc}
\begin{document}
{\small\setcellgapes{8pt}\makegapedcells
  \begin{tabular}{@{}rllllll@{}}
    & \nline{6}\\\hline
  a & & & I'd like to center the numbers above. & & & \\
  b & & & (they should also be bold and footnotesize) & & & \\
  c & foo bar & & like thead & & & baz \\
\end{tabular}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Styling with `\theadalign` would be difficult, but `\theadfont` is doable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xinttools}

\newcommand{\headalign}{\multicolumn{1}{c}}

\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\footnotesize}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ r *{6}{l} }
    \xintFor* #1 in {\xintSeq{1}{6}}\do{&\headalign{\theadfont{#1}}}\\
    %       & \nline{6} \\ %(was for comparison)
  \hline
  a & & & I'd like to center the numbers above. & & & \\
  b & & & (they should also be bold and footnotesize) & & & \\
  c & foo bar & & like thead & & & baz
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: to create arithmetic sequence, for example `\xintSeq[3]{2}{10}` will expand to `{2}{5}{8}` which is then picked up by the `\xintFor*` loop.

Comment: for more or less random numbers, input them explicitely: `\xintFor* #1 in {{27}{-15}{9}{666}{3}{0}}\do{...}` for example.

Comment: nice. I did not know of this package. In fact I changed my mind about using `makecell` in general, because all of the functionality I need is supported in other packages in my project, or with readable and reasonable customization.

Comment: @Bart admission of guilt: I authored the package. Its documentation is last chapter of `xint.pdf` (texdoc xint): `Macros of the xinttools package`. It is independent of rest of xint libraries.

Answer (score 3):

The following provides a partial solution to your question - applying `\theadfont` to each entry within `\nline` - via `\nheadline`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makecell,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nheadline}{%
  \patchcmd{\@@@nline}% <cmd>
    {& \Num}% <search>
    {& \theadfont\Num}% <replace>
    {}{}% <success><failure>
  \theadfont\nline
}
\makeatother

\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ r *{6}{l} }
    & \nheadline{6} \\
    & \nline{6}     \\
  \hline
  a & & & I'd like to center the numbers above. & & & \\
  b & & & (they should also be bold and footnotesize) & & & \\
  c & foo bar & & like thead & & & baz \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

---

The problem with adding alignment is that you're required to use `\multicolumn{1}{<align>}` for every element, which has to be the *first* entry within the cell that it's used. The following example defines `\createheadline{<num>}` to create the appropriate headline combination that includes `\multicolumn{1}{c}` with each header element. You can use it outside of the `tabular` or (as I did) in the first cell that doesn't have anything else in it header-wise.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makecell,multido}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\headalign}{\multicolumn{1}{c}}
\newcommand{\createheadline}[1]{%
  \def\@@@headline{}%
  {%
  \let\headalign\relax
  \let\theadfont\relax
  \multido{\i=1+1}{#1}{%
    \edef\x{\noexpand\gdef\noexpand\@@@headline{\@@@headline & \headalign{\theadfont\i}}}\x%
  }%
  \expandafter\xdef\expandafter\@@@headline\expandafter{\expandafter\@gobble\@@@headline}%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\setheadline}{\@@@headline}

\makeatother

\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ r *{6}{l} }
  \createheadline{6}  & \setheadline \\
    & \nline{6} \\
  \hline
  a & & & I'd like to center the numbers above. & & & \\
  b & & & (they should also be bold and footnotesize) & & & \\
  c & foo bar & & like thead & & & baz
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I'm accepting @jfbu's answer because it is more readable, and I'm able to easily create sequences that don't start on one. I'ts not quite as described in makecell's docs (`\nline[1][4]{3}` ) but I have no hard requirements.